# Where can I find a package to help configure role-based security for application components?

Tags: .net, security, access-control

This is not a greenfield project, so I don't have the opportunity to implement something [like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163807.aspx). What I need is a datastore with, say, users, roles, applications, application "areas", and other functional units, with a UI to configure each. I also need a library that will allow for code like:

```
if (!Security.HasAccess(userId, appName, functionalArea,...))
{
    throw new SecurityException("User does not have rights to...");
}
```

This seems like the sort of problem that gets solved over and over. Is there something out there I can buy or grab that will fulfill these requirements?

Answer (score 1):

how about AzMan ? its a framework from MS to help with RBAC authorization, and it has a GUI

[here`s a good starter how-to video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/donovanf/Demystified-Series-Programming-AzMan). use the WMV download link on the right,
since the player doesnt work (for me at least)